# How to include Silverlight on HTML page with object tag?

Tags: silverlight

I want to include a silverlight application (.xap file) inside a HTML page.

Using these [MSDN instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx) I create this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Test Silverlight Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>

<object id="SilverlightPlugin1" width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="MultiplePages.xap"/>

    <!-- Display installation image. -->
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" 
        style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" 
            alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" 
            style="border-style: none"/>
    </a>
</object>
    </body>
</html>
```

but when I view it in Firefox I get a pop-up asking if I want to run the .xap file:

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/silverlightPopup.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/silverlightPopup.png)

What HTML/Object code do I need to use so that the Silverlight application simply runs inside the browser instead of the browser asking to execute it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the server have the registered MIME type of application/x-silverlight-app for the XAP extension?

Comment: thanks, that is my developement machine on which I installed visual web developer and blend, don't know why it does that, in any case, tried it on other machines and it works, e.g.: http://tanguay.info/web/examples/silverlightInfoFlip

Answer (score 3):

You are not running the page via the development web server but your file system.
If you run the page from the development web server or IIS, it should run fine.

You can see this from the URL in the browser: it is not http:// but file://